# How to install DataServicesServer on WSO2 ESB 4.9.0?

Tags: wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

Does anyone know how to install DataServicesServer on wso2esb 4.9.0 ? It's not in the repository of carbon 4.4.0 (on which I'm fairly sure esb 4.9.0 is based).

Repository url that I was looking at: http://product-dist.wso2.com/p2/carbon/releases/4.4.0

Comment: Yes, DSS that is not available, you can wait or use ESB 4.8.1 version which has DSS feature.

Comment: Ok, so theoretically i could install old dss (carbon 4.2.0 (?)) on the same server on another carbon and this way i would have new ESB and old dss, right?

Comment: Yes, you can have running separate instance of carbon (DSS).

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 ESB is based on carbon 4.4.0. Therefore, the corresponding P2 repository is http://product-dist.wso2.com/p2/carbon/releases/wilkes/